# Optimizing PostGIS k-nearest neighbour function for large amount of polygons?

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor

I created a function for identifying the K nearest neighbours for every municipality, which works fine, but when I use this function for a large amount of municipalities (over 2900) it takes over 2 minutes. The function is defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION KNN(k int,m_id int) RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
SELECT  mun2.id AS m2_id
  FROM municipality AS mun1, municipality AS mun2
  WHERE mun1.id = m_id AND mun1.id != mun2.id
  GROUP BY m2_id, mun1.geom
  ORDER BY mun1.geom <#> mun2.geom
  LIMIT k
$$ LANGUAGE sql
```

Then I run query

```
SELECT m.id, KNN(30,m.id)
FROM municipality AS m
ORDER BY id
```

Is there any way to optimize my function?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but when you're looking for nearest neighbors of multiple points at the same time, there are more efficient algorithms. Try searching for nearest neighbor algorithm or something similar.

Comment: Please post your explain. In general, the <#> requires a constant on the right hand side, and so is not efficient for such queries. Sadly, this usually means falling back to ST_DWithin, which is super fast as it will use the spatial index, but requires a search distance parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using <#> will only compare bounding boxes.

If you have PostGIS 2.2 (or greater in the future) you can use <-> operator to get the real distance calculation. That means that after the index search a recheck is done to find out the real distance.

Second, as John B commented, the knn-functions need a constant to work with. Since you are building a function you can achieve that with plpgsql by building the query in the function.

But there is also a trick to solve this. You can use the keyword LATERAL which gives access to previous tables in the query inside a sub-query.

Then, if you for instance wants the 5 closest municipality to all municipalities you can do something like this:

```
SELECT  mun2.id AS m2_id
  FROM municipality AS mun1 CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  (
        SELECT id from  municipality 
        where id != mun1.id 
        order by geom<->mun1.geom limit 5
   ) AS mun2
```

This will trigger the index to kick in.

Not exactly what you wanted, but I wanted to make the example as clean as possible and I think you figure out to get what you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. To use the <#> was not a right way, now I understand. @Nicklas your query is much more faster, around 30 seconds... thanks

Comment: Great, It is the recheck that takes time. When the index have done it's job the ordinary distance functions have to check which one really is closest. And unfortunately that is the worst conditions for the distance functions to work under as it stands now, comparing polygons that has overlapping bboxes. So, 30 seconds seems reasonable.